# Error while extracting response for type [class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8];

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, resttemplate

I'm trying to send a POST request from my spring boot application to a third party API and return a HTML response. When I post data, it gives an error as follows. My requirement is to pass data from frontend to spring boot application and call the Third party API in the post method and return the response HTML to frontend again.

```
Error while extracting response for type [class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 7, column: 2]
```

My post request code is as follows. Can you help me to solve this issue.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/bu")
public class ShopPostController {

    @PostMapping("/shop")
    public String shopUser (@Valid @RequestBody ShopUserRequest shopUserRequest) {

        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "https://sandbox.payhere.lk/pay/checkout";

        // create headers
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        // set `content-type` header
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        // set `accept` header
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        // create a post object
        ShopUser post = new ShopUser(
                shopUserRequest.getId(),
                shopUserRequest.getSessionid(),
                shopUserRequest.getFirst_name(),
                shopUserRequest.getLast_name(),
                shopUserRequest.getPhone(),
            
                );


        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();

         //Add the Jackson Message converter

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();



        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
        messageConverters.add(converter);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);



        // build the request
        HttpEntity<ShopUser> entity = new HttpEntity<>(post, headers);

        // send POST request
        return restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity,  String.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error, because your URL returns HTML page instead of JSON.